# Opening a new form from an existing one - Is this acceptable

Tags: c++, qt

I am currently opening anew form using the following method

```
void MyForm::MySlot()
{
    //This method loads up te form for historical feeds
    NewForm *w = new NewForm(); 
    w->show();
}
```

Is this way acceptable for opening a new form. Also how would I know when to delete the `w` pointer when the form closes ?

What I am thinking is setting up a signal which would trigger when the form is closed. The slot of that signal would delete w. Is this an acceptable way or is there a faster way to accomplish this ?

Comment: Unless its a referenced object somewhere else, `delete w` should work. Haven't used qt in a little while, but I do not think this will exist anywhere else so this should be safe to do.

Comment: Is this form (`MyForm`) going to be a main one (closing the other one never ends the program and closing this one always does)?

Comment: No it is not going to be the main one

Comment: @Rajeshwar, Well, there goes my idea. I really don't know if there is a better way than the slot for it closing then. I haven't had to deal with this kind of situation. Are you sure you need the `new`? You could have one (or a vector etc.) as a data member and just call `show()` in there.

Answer (score 0):

Set the [Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose attribute](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum):

```
w->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
```

This way, Qt's memory management system will deal with it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close the form, but use it later, set the new form's parent to the main form. That way, when the main form is deleted, Qt will handle deleting the new form too.